# Error: "To build a Debian Package you must install stdeb (pip install std eb)" when installing dpkt (Python 3.5.2)

Tags: python-3.x, dpkt

I'm trying to install dpkt package using pip (Python 3.5.2):

```
pip install dpkt
```

The installation fails giving this error:

```
Collecting dpkt
  Using cached dpkt-1.8.8.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\ic21328\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-e0wstmu2\dpkt\setup.py
", line 26
        print 'To build a Debian Package you must install stdeb (pip install std
eb)'

   ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\ic21328\
AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-e0wstmu2\dpkt\
```

I've successfully installed the stdeb package using pip, but the same error still occurs.
How can I install dpkt?

Answer (score 0):

I got this same error. If you look more closely you can actually see that it is producing a syntax error on the dpkt package and not printing the error asking for you to install stdeb.

My solution was not ideal and involved using python 2.7 which worked fine for my particular use case.